# Why doesn't it shake?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get a picture to shake when you hover above it. This is what i have tried so far:

Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>TEST</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<style>

</style>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Hover above the picture</p>
<img src="pfeil.png" id="toggle">

<script>
 $( document ).hover(function() {
 $( "#toggle" ).effect( "shake" );
 });
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: What isn't working? You haven't really asked a full question here (except in the title).

Comment: Works fine here http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/LGPZVe (shakes when you hover anywhere in the document, because you've attached `hover()` to the document, not the image -- but still)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Community Response

Here is a possible solution:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(document).hover(function () {
    $("#toggle").effect("shake");
  });
});
```

Your original code worked for me, but what I have experienced in my time using jQuery, you should always wrap your jQuery `onready`, like I did above.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably achieve this with just CSS:

```
@keyframes thumb {
  0% { transform: translateX(5px); }
  50% { transform: translateX(-5px); }
  100% { transform: translateX(5px); }
}

img#toggle:hover
{
  animation-name: thumb;
  animation-duration: 200ms;
  transform-origin:50% 50%;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the picture to shake when you hover over it with jQuery UI, you need to select the id of the image element, rather than the entire document:

```
 $('#toggle').hover(function() {
    $("#toggle").effect("shake");
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

Bind the handler to the body instead of the window and see if that works.

```
$( "body" ).hover(function() {
 $( "#toggle" ).effect( "shake" );
 });
```

Answer (score -2):

Like mcgraphic said: unless this is homework, you can just use css

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/shake-css-keyframe-animation/